# Simplifying P AND (P OR NOT Q)

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can I simplify this? I've tried invoking Demorgan's Law and I get

P AND (NOT (NOT P AND Q)) but I can't seem to simplify this further.

The answer is P, but how can I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(P+\overline{Q})=P+P\overline{Q}=P$$

Comment: How did you go from P OR (P AND Q) to P?

Comment: @Jason In an intuitive sense, $P\overline{Q}$ will only be true if $P$ is true, and will be false if it isn't, so $P\overline{Q}$ will be obsolete in $P+P\overline{Q}$ since we *don't need to care* about the values of $Q$.
More "algebraic" explanation: $$P+P\overline{Q}=P(\underbrace{1+\overline{Q}}_{1})=P$$

Comment: It's also known as the law of Absorption.  You can also verify it directly with truth-tables.

Comment: @Bill Province Yes I tried to use the absorption law, but can't I only use it when Q isn't negated? I.e., P + PQ = P, but P + P~Q can't be simplified by the absorption law, can it?

Comment: @Jason If you call R = ~Q then you have P + PR.

Comment: This may somewhat depend on how strict the deductive system is that you are using.  However, in many deductive systems I have seen, you can substitute expressions for the variables in the axioms freely.  Hence, as @Jason suggests, treating R as ~Q allows this operation.  Similarly, if you had P + P(ABC + DE), you should still be able to use absorption.  Or, if you are able to introduce new variables via definitions (as Jason has done), you can accomplish the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as (P AND P) OR (P AND NOT Q).

This is true if and only if P is true.  If P is false, it makes both arguments of the 'OR' false.

Answer (score 2):

$P \land (P \lor \lnot Q) = (P \land P) \lor (P \land \lnot Q) = P \lor (P\land \lnot Q)$

If $P$ then clearly this expression holds. If $\lnot P$ then $\lnot (P\land \lnot Q)$ so we see the expression depends entirely on $P$.

Stuff below is why you were confused, be cause it is not equal to $P$.

$P \land \lnot (\lnot P \land Q) = P \land (\lnot (\lnot P) \lor \lnot Q) = P \land (P \lor \lnot Q) = (P\land P) \lor (P \land \lnot Q) = P\land \lnot Q$

Comment: The answer in the book says P, and so does the truth table, if you draw one

Comment: I was confused too and so I deleted my answer. The question is in the title, the text is what he tried.

Comment: @Jason A truth table would be sufficient to show that the statements are equivalent.

Comment: I need to do it with the basic laws though, such as demorgans, commutative, idempotent, etc

Comment: O ha ha. That's what I get for not reading the question more carefully!

Answer (score 1):

Shahar's answer is the most direct.  However, sometimes, these can be a bit tricky when first starting out.  What I frequently like to do when handling these sort of problems is to use this identity:

```
phi(a, b, c, d, ...) = a AND phi(TRUE, b, c, d, ...) OR
                       NOT a AND phi(FALSE, b, c, d, ...)
```

I call this the 'factor' identity for lack of a better name, but there is probably an 'official' name out there somewhere.

Applying this to your problem, I would see that:

```
P AND (NOT (NOT P AND Q)) = P AND (P OR NOT Q))  /* Demorgan's */
                          = P AND (TRUE AND (TRUE OR NOT Q)) OR
                            NOT P AND (FALSE AND (FALSE OR NOT Q)) /*Factor*/
                          = P AND TRUE OR NOT P AND FALSE
                          = P
```

Be warned that this process is not necessarily the fastest method, but it always leads to simpler expressions.